# Debugging IEnumerable: get current line number of Iterator block

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, ienumerable, coroutine

I have an Iterator block, used to emulate a coroutine:

```
public class Event{}
public IEnumerable<Event> Coroutine()
{
    // ... do stuff
    yield return new Event();
    // ... do stuff
    yield return new Event();
    // ... do stuff
    yield return new Event();
    // ... do stuff
}
```

When I enumerate this, can I somehow find out in the debugger which line was executed most recently, or on which line the state machine would continue?

```
foreach (var event in Coroutine())
{
    // <-- breakpoint here
    // Can I determine the 'current' line number in Coroutine() ?
    // NOTE: This foreach loop is inside a library, I can debug it but not modify it
}
```

I know that the IEnumerable block is translated to a state machine by the .net compiler, and there is no current "StackFrame" of this block, while the program is stopped outside the block. But somewhere the state machine must store where to continue the execution. Can I access this information?

Background: Why do I need this?

I am trying to debug a simulation using the [Dessert Framework](https://github.com/pomma89/Dessert), (similar to [SimPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SimPy)). 
In this framework, for better or worse, all simulated tasks are implemented as coroutines using `yield return` Iterator blocks.

When debugging such a simulation, it is critical to find out the current state of each simulated task.

In the example given above, I can of course simply count the number of times the breakpoint is hit, and know exactly where my iterator block is currently.
But the case I am trying to debug has multiple coroutines all running concurrently, generating and consuming resources, and waiting for each other to complete. The IEnumerables are not consumed by my code, but by the Framework itself.

Comment: You don't need to *emulate* coroutines. In most cases you can use Task. For event processing specifically you can use ReactiveX. Even with enumerables though, you can use the [Enumerable.Select()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) overload that provides the index to the selector function

Comment: What if you transform your code to `while (enumerator.MoveNext())` and inspect `enumerator.Current`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is a discrete event simulation, not an application running in realtime. (Think SimPy). I don't think tasks are the proper tool for this, but I might be wrong. But in any case, the used library requires these coroutines.

Comment: @HugoRune you could use `CoRoutine().Select((evt,idx)=>new {evt,idx})` to get both the event and index

Comment: @HugoRune coroutines aren't either in that case. This is *not* a coroutine, it's an iterator that returns an IEnumerable<Event>. This means that you can use all LINQ methods and Enumerable extentions

Comment: The iterator block is consumed by the framework. I can modify the iterator block, and I can of course enumerate it myself. But I am trying to debug the case when multiple such coroutines are running at the same time inside the framework and interacting with each other (producing and consuming resources, waiting for each other to complete, etc.) .

Comment: Yes, this information is stored in the internal classes. No, you can't access those, because there's no way to really talk about them in the static C# code. If the `Event`s can be distinguished, you can inspect the enumerator's `Current`, per the other suggestions. Otherwise, you're out of luck, unless you really fancy reflecting over the type, hoping that your version of the compiler uses an `int` member named `<>1__state` as well (this is not guaranteed) and then trying to map this internal number to a line number somehow. And praying profusely it won't break on the next release.

Comment: If you're really invested in this approach, it may even be worth considering tweaking the compiler (i.e. using a custom Roslyn) so it exposes the enumerator states explicitly. But if you're willing to go *that* far, you may as well just explicitly add coroutines to the language, complete with debugging support...

Comment: @HugoRune that's why insist that this isn't a coroutine and there's no reason to emulate coroutines. That library tried to *emulate* something that was already available in Rx, the IObservable<T>. Rx allows you to use LINQ-like queries on event streams, as if they were an IEnumerable<T> or IQueryable<T>. As a result, it *can't* use many of the facilites that would make what you ask trivial.

Comment: @HugoRune that said, you *can* convert an Enumerable to Observable and vice-versa. That could allow you to duplicate events and use one stream for monitoring and pass the other as an IEnumerable to the SDK

Comment: @JeroenMostert Not willing to go quite that far :) In that case I'd rather add a log command in front of all 1000 different yield returns.

Comment: Using an IL post-processor of some kind to add the metadata you need does not sound like a half bad approach, actually.

Comment: @HugoRune or use a "dirty" `Select()` that logs the entries but returns the original event, eg `.Select((evt,i)=>{ log.Whatever(evt,i); return evt;})`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That is an excellent suggestion, I think I can do that